# PHP Form Validation Issue - Validate Large Set of Input Fields

Tags: php, validation, forms

I have 20 "sets" of input fields in my HTML Form.

Here is a taster:

```
<input id="a1height" />
<input id="a1width" />
<input id="a1length" />
<input id="a1weight" />

<input id="a2height" />
<input id="a2width" />
<input id="a2length" />
<input id="a2weight" />
...and so on
```

Now, I need a way of:

a) storing all the values in one variable with pipes(|) between the height, width, length & weight and \n between each set
b) if one or more of the fields in a set is incomplete my variable $errors is set to true.

I'm at a little bit of a loss on how I can achieve this. Never really good with loops :'(

Can someone explain how to do this?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using an `$errors` array that stores all errors and an `$all` string that contains your desired output. To check, put `var_dump( $all);` at the end of the script.

```
$errors = array();
$all = '';

// Loop over the values 1 through 20
foreach( range( 1, 20) as $i)
{
    // Create an array that stores all of the values for the current number
    $values = array( 
        'a' . $i . 'height' => $_POST['a' . $i . 'height'], 
        'a' . $i . 'width' => $_POST['a' . $i . 'width'], 
        'a' . $i . 'length' => $_POST['a' . $i . 'length'], 
        'a' . $i . 'weight' => $_POST['a' . $i . 'weight']
    );

    // Make sure at least one submitted value is valid, if not, skip these entirely
    if( count( array_filter( array_map( 'is_numeric', $values))))
    {
         // This basically checks if there's at least one numeric entry for the current $i
         continue; // Skip
    }

    // Validate every value
    foreach( $values as $key => $value)
    {
        if( empty( $value))
        {
            $errors[] = "Value $key is not set";
        }
        // You can add more validation in here, such as:
        if( !is_numeric( $value))
        {
            $errors[] = "Value $key contains an invalid value '$value'";
        }
    }

    // Join all of the values together to produce the desired output
    $all .= implode( '|', $values) . "\n";
}
```

To nicely format the errors, try something like this:

```
// If there are errors
if( count( $errors) > 0)
{
    echo '<div class="errors">';

    // If there is only one, just print the only message
    if( count( $errors) == 1)
    {
        echo $errors[0];
    }
    // Otherwise format them into an unordered list
    else
    {
        echo '<ul>';
        echo '<li>' . implode( '</li><li>', $errors) . '</li>';
        echo '</ul>';
    }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I'm after. I'm just rejigging it right now. Will post back shortly.

Comment: Just make sure you use the same `name` attribute on your form fields as you have IDs and this should work!

Comment: Brilliant. I'm working away on it just now. Will post back here later tonight or tomorrow with how I ge on. Thanks so much again for taking the time to help out. Very, very much appreciated.

Comment: Trying this out right now and it works great. Can you explain how I list the $errors in a user-friendly manner? Currently doing `var_dump($errors);` is not so great. Again, I'm in your debt with this. Stellar help here.

Comment: Many thanks, Nick. For all input fields, I also have placeholder text. value="Weight" etc.. Is this worth considering when rejigging the code? Thanks again

Comment: Not really. If they fail to replace your placeholder text, they'll get an error (because of the `is_numeric` check), so you shouldn't have to edit the code to detect that error.

Comment: The reformatting works brilliantly. Thank you. You're going to hate me, but all my fields initially have placeholder text as the 'Value'. So Weight has "Weight(kg)" and Height has "Height(cm)" - is there a way that if a whole set contains these, that it ignores the set and doesn't throw an error? Realise this is above and beyond the question so happy to take to a new question if it suits.

Comment: It's just that the minimum number of 'sets' they can complete out of 20 is 1. So they *could* potentially just complete one. Is there a way to ignore other sets that contain the default placeholder text as the value? Thanks again for all your help here.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my answer with a solution to only completing 1.

Comment: Thanks, Nick :-) I'll work on this and let you know how I get on. Many thanks again for taking the time to help out. Means a lot.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7807/discussion-between-mcgarriers-and-nickb)

Answer (score 1):

First should create NAME properties for your inputs, as these will be used in the _POST array to specify your values.

```
<input id="a1height" name="a1height" />
<input id="a1width" name="a1width" />
<input id="a1length" name="a1length" />
<input id="a1weight" name="a1weight" />

<input id="a2height" name="a2height" />
<input id="a2width" name="a2width" />
<input id="a2length" name="a2length" />
<input id="a2weight" name="a2weight" />
```

Then, after you submit, loop through the post array creating your pipe-joined varibles

```
$errors = false;
$string = "";
$current_prefix = '';
foreach($_POST as $key=>$posted_value){
   if(trim($posted_value)==""){ //if the value is empty or just spaces
      $errors = TRUE;
   }
   //find out if we need to add a new line
   $number = preg_replace ('/[^\d]/', '', $key) //get the numbers of the name only
   if ($current_prefix != $number){
       $string .= "\n";
   } else {
      $string .= '|';
   }
   $string .= $posted_value;
}
```

Comment: Taking a look just now. Happy to 'stay on the line' as I try it out? :)

Comment: Oh, hey, I have some other fields in my form (name, email etc). Is there a way to narrow down the foreach loop to just the a1, a2 type fields?

Comment: Yeah, if you have other fields that are posting, you might be better off with using a for loop (`for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){...` kind of like how nickb does it

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array to store your values.
2. Loop through your input fields, parsing the prefix (ie 'a1') from the field type (ie 'height')
3. Insert the values into the array like this:

   `$your_array['a1']['height'] = $_POST['a1height'];`
4. Remember to validate and sanitize your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your html so the posted fields come in a nicely formatted array:

```
<input name="a1[height]" />
<input name="a1[width]" />
<input name="a1[length]" />
<input name="a1[weight]" />

<input name="a2[height]" />
<input name="a2[width]" />
<input name="a2[length]" />
<input name="a2[weight]" />
```

That way you get an array that's easy to use. You could access `$_POST['a1']['height']` or `$_POST['a1']['length']` or `$_POST['a2']['height']`.